# Bash script to move screen shots from desktop to folder

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I have a ton of screenshots on my desktop (it's the default location where they're saved) with titles of the form "Screen Shot 2020-10-11 at 7.08.12 PM.png" and I'd like to use a bash script with regex on the "Screen Shot" bit to move any such file from my desktop into a folder I created called "screenshots".

Right now, I'm playing around with `find . -regex Screen*.*?.png` but it's not quite working (it gives `find: Screen Shot 2020-10-11 at 7.11.09 PM.png: unknown primary or operator`).

I'm also not sure how I'd even use the output once it does find all the correct files to move them to a folder. Could you somehow iterate over all files in a folder using `for i in seq 1 100` or something of the like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually even need -regex here:

```
find . -type f -name 'Screen Shot*png' -maxdepth 1 -exec echo mv "{}" screenshots \;
```

You can run this command safely as it will not do anything but print
what it *would* do. Remove `echo` to actually run `mv`.

All options used are documented in `man find` but in short:

`-type f` will make `find` look only for files, not directories. This
is useful in case you have a directory that matches `-name` - we don't
want to touch it.

`-maxdepth 1` will only look fire files in the same directory level -
it's very useful here because you might already have some files that
match the -name present in `screenshots` directory - we want to leave
them alone.

`-name` accepts shell pattern, not regex. We could of course use `-regex` here but I prefer `-name` because shell patterns are shorter and easier to use here.

`{}` is a placeholder that will be replaced will the name of found
file.

`\;` is a *literal* semicolon, escaped to prevent it from being
interpreted by shell that ends command specified with `-exec`.

Comment: This did it! But I don't really understand it. Why the `-type f`, and how come `Shot*png` works - I thought that `*` would only regex for one character (and why don't we need `-regex` here?). I also don't understand what the depth option and `exec` and `{}` are doing here. I'd love your thoughts on how you came up with it and how I might be able to write these myself in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I will look on the man page; but why the escape for semicolon at end, and what does "{}" do here?

Answer (score 2):

Taking the regex at face value (probably a mistake), you should use single quotes around the regex:

```
find . -regex 'Screen*.*?.png'
```

This prevents the shell from expanding it, leaving that to [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html).  Then to move the files to the `~/screenshots` directory (change the name to match the directory you want to use), if you have GNU `mv`, you can use:

```
find . -regex 'Screen*.*?.png' -exec mv -t ~/screenshots {} +
```

This executes a single `mv` command to move many files to the target directory, reducing the number of times the `mv` is executed.  It might still be executed multiple times, but it will be many fewer times than the alternative.

If you don't have GNU `mv` with the (very useful) `-t` option, then you should use:

```
find . -regex 'Screen*.*?.png' -exec mv {} ~/screenshots ';'
```

This executes one `mv` command for each file found, but is more portable.

The primary problem you ran into was that the shell was expanding what you wrote into a list of file names, and then `find` didn't understand what you meant. Using the quotes prevents the shell from expanding the 'regex'. You can add an `echo` to the other commands before the `mv` to see what would be executed.

However, I'm not sure whether you know what your regex matches.  It isn't clear that the regex given is a valid regex for `find` — though it mostly works as a PCRE (Perl-compatible) regular expression.  By default, GNU [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Name) uses GNU Emacs [regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Regexps), but you can control the dialect of regular expression it uses.  The options available include Emacs, POSIX Awk, POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BRE), POSIX `egrep`, and POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE).  It doesn't include PCRE.  What you supply is more like a shell glob, and the `-name` operator handles globbing names.

It's quite probable that you should be using the `-name` operator, using a command along the lines of:

```
find . -name 'Screen Shot *.png' -exec mv -t ~/screenshots {} +
```

Comment: What does it even do? I'm unclear on what this achieves, since nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: The first version, with no `-exec` option, prints the names of the files that match your `regex`.  I'm not sure whether you know what your regex matches.  It's quite possible that you should be using `-name 'Screen*.*.png'` or even `-name 'Screen Shot *.png'`.  But the primary problem you ran into was that the shell was expanding what you wrote into a list of file names, and then `find` didn't understand what you meant.  Using the quotes prevents the shell from expanding the 'regex'. You can add an `echo` to the other commands to see what would be executed.

Comment: This is great - thanks! Any tips on learning these nuances of bash utilities in the future?

Comment: @oguzismail — it could be a valid PCRE regex, but it is likely that `find` does not support them. My previous comment discusses the issue.  I've not had time to integrate the commentary into my answer.